# Average function value over an Interval

Tags: numerical-integration, intervals, averages

What is the best way to find the average value of a function over a specific interval in *Mathematica*? I can not figure it out. I have two points on the interval and need to find the average value.

Comment: `NIntegrate[f[x], {x, a, b}]/(b - a)`

Comment: How would you do it on paper?

Comment: To those voting to close, I don't think the folks over at math.se will appreciate migrating these kind of questions.

Answer (score 5):

I was just inspired by @kglr to illustrate:

```
f[x_] := 1/1000 x^4 - 280/1000 x^2 + 25;
sim[a_, b_, n_] := 
  With[{u = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{a, b}], n]},
   {#, f@#} & /@ u];
Manipulate[
 Module[{res = sim[a, b, n], mn = Integrate[f[x], {x, a, b}]/(b - a)},
  Show[Plot[f[x], {x, a, b}],
   ListPlot[res, PlotStyle -> Red], 
   GridLines -> {None, {{mn, 
       Black}, {Mean[res[[All, 2]]], {Red, Dashed}}}}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-12, 12}, {0, 25}}]],
 {a, -12, 0}, {b, 0, 12}, {n, PowerRange[10, 10000, 10]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

See also [Average Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AverageFunction.html) and [Average Value of a Function](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/AverageValueOfAFunction/).

Say you have messured values and express them with the Function f(x):

```
f[x_] := 1/1000 x^4 - 280/1000 x^2 + 25
```

You can Plot that Function:

```
Plot[f[x], {x, -15, 15}]
```

[image]

And you like to find the average value as of -12 ... 12

```
a = -12; b = 12;

solNI = NIntegrate[f[x], {x, a, b}]/(b - a)
```

> 15.7072

```
Plot[{f[x], solNI}, {x, -15, 15}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the built-in functions `Expectation` or `NExpectation` taking the function argument `x` to be uniformly distributed over the interval `{a,b}`.

```
f[x_] := 1/1000 x^4 - 280/1000 x^2 + 25

Expectation[f[x], Distributed[x, UniformDistribution[{a, b}]]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
NExpectation[f[x], Distributed[x, UniformDistribution[{-12, 12}]]]
```

> 15.7072

```
NExpectation[x Sin[x], 
Distributed[x, UniformDistribution[{-Pi, 2 Pi}]]]
```

> -0.333333